# Graphaware neo4j timetree will only support day resolution

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, graphaware

I'm currently trying out GraphAware's timetree plugin.

However I have not been able to stop using the default resolution of 1 day.

My configuration in neo4j.conf is as follows:

```
#For the framework to work at all, you need this
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware

# Runtime must be enabled like this
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

# A Runtime module that takes care of attaching the events like this (TT is the ID of the module)
com.graphaware.module.TT.1=com.graphaware.module.timetree.module.TimeTreeModuleBootstrapper

# autoAttach must be set to true
com.graphaware.module.TT.autoAttach=true

# Optionally, nodes which represent events and should be attached automatically have to be defined (defaults to nodes with label Event)
com.graphaware.module.TT.event=hasLabel('Message')

# Optionally, a resolution can be specified (defaults to DAY)
com.graphaware.module.TT.resolution=MILLISECOND

# Optionally, a time zone can be specified (defaults to UTC)
com.graphaware.module.TT.timezone=GMT+1
```

The interesting part of the config I think is `com.graphaware.module.TT.resolution=MILLISECOND`.

When I make the call `CREATE (e:Email {text: "I used the timetree"}) WITH e
CALL ga.timetree.events.attach({node: e, time: 1463659567468, relationshipType: "SENT_ON"}) YIELD node RETURN node;`

I get the following data created:

[image: Created data]

Can anyone see something I'm missing?

Comment: OK, so it didn't take me too long to realse that I could pass the desired resolution in the cypher command used to create the tree, so I have a work around, but still curious why the configuration from neo4j.conf wont apply by default.

Comment: The configuration doesnt apply by default because you can define multiple timetree modules in the same configuration and we can't automatically detect which to use. But a good point would be to pass the module id and so all parameters of the config for this module would be applied. Thanks for using our products

Comment: The configuration in this file is currently used when you do automatic event attachment ( https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree#automatic-event-attachment )